# aws adding elastic IP

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-elastic-ip

I need help with my AWS EC2 Instance. I had one public IP on it, and it worked great. But now I need a second public IP, and for that I activated a Elastic IP and assigned it to the Instance over the AWS dashboard. My server is a Ubuntu 16.04. But I do not see the new IP in my Instance over the command line. What do I need to do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html) for managing multiple ip.

Relevant part is that you need to assign a secondary private ip to your istance and then you can add a second elastic ip.

> To assign a secondary private IPv4 address to a network interface
>
> ```
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Network Interfaces, and then select the network interface attached to the instance.
>
> Choose Actions, Manage IP Addresses.
>
> Under IPv4 Addresses, choose Assign new IP.
>
> Enter a specific IPv4 address that's within the subnet range for the instance, or leave the field blank to let Amazon select an IP
> ```
>
> address for you.
>
> ```
> (Optional) Choose Allow reassignment to allow the secondary private IP address to be reassigned if it is already assigned to
> ```
>
> another network interface.
>
> ```
> Choose Yes, Update.
> ```

Then

> To associate an Elastic IP address with a secondary private IPv4
>   address in EC2-VPC
>
> ```
> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose Elastic IPs.
>
> Choose Actions, and then select Associate address.
>
> For Network interface, select the network interface, and then select the secondary IP address from the Private IP list.
>
> Choose Associate.
> ```

I try to avoid the need of more public ip on a single server and looks like AWS thinks that having "elastic ip" is generally not needed as you have just 5 of them by default unless you ask for more.

Comment: I already did all that stuff, but I do not see the IP inside the virtual machine with for example "ip addr show".

Comment: I just did that "stuff" too, and it works. Create a new interface and assign it to an ec2 instance. after few seconds you will see it with ip addr show. Then go under elastic ip, allocate a new ip, select the instance second eth and you are done. Super easy.

Comment: In addition to the steps above, Ubuntu EC2 instances will also need some configuration as per this KB document: [adding a secondary network interface to Ubuntu](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-ubuntu-secondary-network-interface/).